# Rails embed document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

In rails is there anything available that if a user uploads a document to me through paperclip (like maybe a .doc or .pdf or .odf, etc.) That i can embed there document into my page (Like perhaps is there some sort of gem available to handle that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the pdf part of my problem.
theres a simple html line that solves this

```
<iframe src="thispdf.pdf" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I've tried the same with .odt, but this just downloads the file (maybe this was more of an html problem than rails) -- note i only tested this in chrome

Answer (score 1):

By embed do you mean display? There's no native way to display any of those documents in html, so you will have to either somehow convert them to html or use another layer, like flash or a third-party tool, to do the embedding for you.

Maybe one of the [embed.ly providers](http://embed.ly/providers) can give a nice display for your documents.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to make mine work in the view (with the example object `@person`) using the most current (as of 2013) [Google Docs embedded pdf code specifications](https://docs.google.com/viewer):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.mysite.com/<%= @person.pdf.url %>&embedded=true" 
width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" >
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```